# React window how to iterate your data?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

```js
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window'
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized-auto-sizer'
const TrackTable = ({ tracks }) => {
    const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
        <div
            className={index % 2 ? 'ListItemOdd' : 'ListItemEven'}
            style={style}>
            Row {index}
        </div>
    )
    const AllRows = () => {
        const arr = [
            { code: '12H', id: '1' },
            { code: '4gf', id: '2' },
        ]
        return arr.map((i, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>{i.code}</div>
        })
    }
    return (
        <AutoSizer>
            {({ height, width }) => (
                <List
                    className="List"
                    height={height}
                    itemCount={tracks.length}
                    itemSize={35}
                    width={width}>
                    {AllRows()}
                </List>
            )}
        </AutoSizer>
    )
}
```

If I put `Row` in the `<List />` just like in the example from the author, it works,

But If i put my data `AllRows` in the `<List />`, I got error `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`. I checked my data is good. So what I did wrong here?

[image]

Here the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughn-react-window-fixed-size-list-vertical-forked-jqmyx?file=/index.js

Comment: How are you implementing List component?

Comment: yes. updated the code

Comment: Not exactly my point. There's probably a line somewhere in list component that calls props.children. The arguments you pass to props.children there are passed to the function between <List> and </List>

Comment: If List or FixedSizeList does not contain a call to props.children then I am wrong about [facc](https://reactpatterns.com/#function-as-children) and see Nokwiw's answer.

Comment: Does removing paranthesis after AllRows without changing anything else make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example . Please check

```
const arr = [
  { code: "12H", id: "1" },
  { code: "4gf", id: "2" }
];
const AllRows = () => arr.map((i, index) => <div key={index}>{i.code}</div>);

const Example = () => (
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
      <List
        className="List"
        height={height}
        itemCount={1000}
        itemSize={35}
        width={width}
      >
        {AllRows}
      </List>
    )}
  </AutoSizer>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `AllRows` without proprty, in this case `tracks` is `undefined` ==> you will have the error `tracks.map is not a function`

to avoid that, call `AllRows` with an array :

```
        <List
            className="List"
            height={height}
            itemCount={tracks.length}
            itemSize={35}
            width={width}>
            {AllRows(yourArray)}
        </List>
```

**EDIT :**

`AllRows` as is defined below, return an array, remove `return` before `tracks.map`  :

```
const AllRows = () => {
        if (tracks.length == 0) return ''
        return tracks.map((i, index) => {
            return <div key={i.index}>{i.code}</div>
        })
    }
```

use that instead :

```
const AllRows = () => {
        if (tracks.length == 0) return <></>
        tracks.map((i, index) => {
            return <div key={i.index}>{i.code}</div>
        })
    }
```

OR :

```
const AllRows = () => {
   if (tracks.length == 0) return <></>
   return (
   {
    tracks.map((i, index) => {
            return <div key={i.index}>{i.code}</div>
        })
   }
          ) 
    }
```

Comment: I update the question and the code

Comment: did you call `AllRows` with a valid array ?

Comment: yes I did call with valid arr

Comment: I just simplified my arr, it has two item inside

Answer (score 1):

addition for above answer, you also can use this :

```
const AllRows = () => {
    (tracks || []).map((i, index) => {
        return <div key={i.index}>{i.code}</div>
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error you mentioned was tracks.map is not defined. This suggests that List components calls its children. From the documentation, the first argument has index and style variables. So you can use:

```
// arr is defined up here
const AllRows = ({ index, style }) => {
  return <div key={index}>{arr[index].code}</div>;
};
```

Or as a more generalized method using closures:

```
const AllRows2 = (arr2) => {
  return ({ index, style }) => {
    return <div key={index}>{arr2[index].code}</div>;
  };
};
```

Then in list component use AllRows2(arr). This probably not required.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughn-react-window-fixed-size-list-vertical-forked-iykzz?file=/index.js:0-962) is an working example.